# CAMEL thread lock on servicemix

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have a problem with camel in ServiceMix.

I made webservice through camel-jetty, camel-recipentlist in servicemix. 
This package is good performance but resource lock and thread full occurred it. This system process 40 Call per second.

The problem is that pool threads aren't released properly sometimes. After 
a few hours following the start of an application I can see using jstack 
tool that some threads are stuck in a WAITING state:

configuration is as follows: 
- servicemix 5.3.0 
- camel 2.13.2 
- using component (camel-jetty , camel-recipentlist  based Spring DSL)

-SOURCE

```
<route customId="true" >
<from uri="direct:giop_addr_async">
    <recipentList>
          <simple>jetty://http://api.host.lm?x=${header.x}&y=${header.y}</simple>
    </recipentList>
    <bean ref="soapDecode" method="userDecode"/>
    <to uri="direct:sendEndPoint">
</route>
<route customId="true>
    <from uri="direct:sendEndPoint">
    <to uri="jetty://http://resultMap?httpClient.soTimeout=80000"/>
</route>
```

-------------- LOG

```
ps -eLf  | wc -l --> 32500 



"CamelJettyClient(0x3d0b240d)-26916" damen prio=10 tid=0x000000000ff69800 nid =0x10ef wating on condition [0x00002b4b3ba3f0000] 
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITNG(parking) 
     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
 - parking to wait for <0x000000006f13f19b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) 
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LocsSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport,java:226) 
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:342) 
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoss(QueuedThreadPool.java:526) 
 at org.eclipse.jetty.tuil.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572) 
 at java.lnag.thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The above log is more than 30000 lines.

Can you suggest what else can be checked? Am I missing something? Or may be 
this is a bug in Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Having threads in a waiting state is not abnormal, but 30.000 threads is a lot.

You are using a `recipientList` : For each combination of x and y, you are creating a new jetty producer. each jetty producer has his own thread pool, and camel keeps in a cache the last producers created: A large number of thread pools and thread are created here.

You don't need a recipientList in order to have a URL built dynamically. You can use the header `Exchange.HTTP_URI` :

for example:

```
<route customId="true" >
<from uri="direct:giop_addr_async">
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri">
          <simple>jetty://http://api.host.lm?x=${header.x}&y=${header.y}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="jetty://http://api.host.lm"/>
    <bean ref="soapDecode" method="userDecode"/>
    <to uri="direct:sendEndPoint">
</route>
<route customId="true>
    <from uri="direct:sendEndPoint">
    <to uri="jetty://http://resultMap?httpClient.soTimeout=80000"/>
</route>
```